# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range

Tags: java, jai, geotools

I recently started my first program with GeoTools in which i was also using JAI- Java Advanced Imaging. I found following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/jaiext/range/Range
>       at it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop.CropDescriptor.(CropDescriptor.java:62)
>       at it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop.CropSpi.updateRegistry(CropSpi.java:56)
>       at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.registerServices(OperationRegistry.java:2056)
>       at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.registerServices(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:620)
>       at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:373)
>       at javax.media.jai.JAI.(JAI.java:566)
>       at com.rgb.NDRI.createNDI(NDRI.java:17)
>       at com.rgb.RGBSpliter.main(RGBSpliter.java:71)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 8 more

The above is what I see in console. I do not know out of all jars in geotools 14.4 which jar is missing.

The code is as below

```
 package com.rgb;
 import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
 import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
 import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.media.jai.*;

 public class NDRI {
 public void createNDI(String file1,String file2) throws IOException{
     // First we open the input images. We assume that each band is in a separate file.
     // We assume that the first image is a near infrared one and that the second is
     // a visible red image -- if you're using Landsat images, those will be bands
     // 4 and 3, respectively.
     PlanarImage iNIR = JAI.create("fileload",file1);
     PlanarImage iVIS = JAI.create("fileload",file2);
     // The pixels on those images must be processed as floating-point values!
     ParameterBlock pbConvert = new ParameterBlock();
     pbConvert.addSource(iNIR);
     pbConvert.add(DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE);
     PlanarImage NIR = JAI.create("format", pbConvert);
     pbConvert = new ParameterBlock();
     pbConvert.addSource(iVIS);
     pbConvert.add(DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE);
     PlanarImage VIS = JAI.create("format", pbConvert);    
     // Calculate the denominator (NIR-VIS).
     ParameterBlock pbd = new ParameterBlock();
     pbd.addSource(NIR);
     pbd.addSource(VIS);
     PlanarImage denominator = JAI.create("subtract",pbd);
     // Calculate the numerator (NIR+VIS).
     ParameterBlock pbn = new ParameterBlock();
     pbn.addSource(NIR);
     pbn.addSource(VIS);
     PlanarImage numerator = JAI.create("add",pbd);
     // Calculate the NDVI.
     ParameterBlock pbNDVI = new ParameterBlock();
     pbNDVI.addSource(denominator);
     pbNDVI.addSource(numerator);
     RenderedImage ndvi = JAI.create("divide",pbNDVI);
     String format="png";
     ImageIO.write(ndvi, format, new File("E:/ndvi_output.png"));

     // Create a GUI to show it. 
    /* JFrame frame = new JFrame("NDVI image");
     DisplayNBImage disp = new DisplayNBImage(ndvi);
     frame.add(new JScrollPane(disp));
     frame.pack();
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);*/

     /*  PlanarImage iNIR = JAI.create("fileload","E:/output/image_red.png");
     PlanarImage iVIS = JAI.create("fileload","E:/output/image_green.png");
     // The pixels on those images must be processed as floating-point values!
     ParameterBlock pbConvert = new ParameterBlock();
     pbConvert.addSource(iNIR);
     pbConvert.add(DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE);
     PlanarImage NIR = JAI.create("format", pbConvert);
     pbConvert = new ParameterBlock();
     pbConvert.addSource(iVIS);
     pbConvert.add(DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE);
     PlanarImage VIS = JAI.create("format", pbConvert);    
     // Calculate the denominator (NIR-VIS).
     ParameterBlock pbd = new ParameterBlock();
     pbd.addSource(NIR);
     pbd.addSource(VIS);
     PlanarImage denominator = JAI.create("subtract",pbd);
     // Calculate the numerator (NIR+VIS).
     ParameterBlock pbn = new ParameterBlock();
     pbn.addSource(NIR);
     pbn.addSource(VIS);
     PlanarImage numerator = JAI.create("add",pbd);
     // Calculate the NDVI.
     ParameterBlock pbNDVI = new ParameterBlock();
     pbNDVI.addSource(denominator);
     pbNDVI.addSource(numerator);
     PlanarImage ndvi = JAI.create("divide",pbNDVI);
     double[][] matrix1 = {{ 1./3, 1./3, 1./3, 0 }};
     ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
      pb.addSource(ndvi);
      pb.add(matrix1);*/

     /* PlanarImage dst = (PlanarImage) JAI.create("bandCombine",pb);



      BufferedImage img = dst.getAsBufferedImage();
     ImageIO.write(img, format, new File("E:/output/ndvi_output.png"));
     System.out.println("ndvi gray scale image created");*/
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using Maven to manage dependencies?

Comment: No I am not using maven. I even added jt-algebra.jar but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the missing Range class here:
https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/tree/master/jt-utilities/src/main/java/it/geosolutions/jaiext/range

So, try to add jt-utilities and jt-iterators to your project.

Comment: I added all jars in geotools 14.2 and the error gone anyways thanks for the help