# vectorize polygon using JTS with range lookup

Tags: java, maven, vectorization, geotools, jai

I try to vectorize an image using java i.e. geotools with JAI.

The code is minimal and works just fine in intelliJ

```
InputStream stringAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputAsciiGrid.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
SimpleFeatureIterator vectorizedFeatures = extractor.execute(input, 0, true, null,
                null, classificationRanges, null).features();
```

My problem is when executing this via maven like:

```
mvn clean package && \
    java -jar target/quickstart-1.0.jar
```

it fails with exception of

```
RangeLookup: No OperationDescriptor is registered in the current operation registry under this name
```

sample code can be found at https://github.com/geoHeil/jts-vectorize

Note, the jar contains the class, but not the `OperationDescriptors` in the `META-INF/registry.jai` files.

```
jar -tf target/quickstart-1.0.jar| grep RangeLookupProcess                                                            
org/geotools/process/raster/RangeLookupProcess.class
```

## edit

I tried to follow [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.geosolutions.jaiext.range.Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651560/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-it-geosolutions-jaiext-range-range)
and added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions.jaiext.iterators</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt-iterators</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

This changes the exception to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/jaiext/utilities/ImageLayout2
    at FooJava.getAsciiGridFromstring(FooJava.java:49)
    at FooJava.main(FooJava.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities.ImageLayout2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
make: *** [run-java] Error 1
```

even though again the class is there:

```
geoheil@geoheilsMacBook ~/Downloads/vectorize/jts-vectorize                                                                 [20:36:45]
> $ jar -tf target/quickstart-1.0.jar| grep ImageLayout2                                                                  [±master ●●]
org/jaitools/imageutils/ImageLayout2.class
```

this seems to be a version mismatch.
When reverting and adding the versions also listed in (https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/18.4/pom.xml#L97):

```
<properties>
    <geotools.version>18.4</geotools.version>
    <jaiext.version>1.0.16</jaiext.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-arcgrid</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-process-raster</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt-rlookup</artifactId>
            <version>${jaiext.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

The error is again the initial one.

### edit 2

Manually registering the missing operation descriptor:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/javax.media.jai.registryFile.jai</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/registryFile.jaiext</resource>
                                </transformer>
```

and adding both files (see names above) with content of:

```
# --- JAI ext manual re-registration ---
descriptor  it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup.RangeLookupDescriptor
```

gives me a new exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp$1.getPropertyNames(RenderedOp.java:1791)
        at javax.media.jai.PropertyEnvironment.mapDefaults(PropertyEnvironment.java:270)
        at javax.media.jai.PropertyEnvironment.getPropertyNames(PropertyEnvironment.java:125)
        at javax.media.jai.WritablePropertySourceImpl.addProperties(WritablePropertySourceImpl.java:298)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createPropertySource(RenderedOp.java:1817)
        at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getPropertyNames(RenderedOp.java:1851)
        at javax.media.jai.PropertySourceImpl.<init>(PropertySourceImpl.java:143)
        at org.geotools.coverage.AbstractCoverage.<init>(AbstractCoverage.java:139)
        at org.geotools.coverage.grid.AbstractGridCoverage.<init>(AbstractGridCoverage.java:102)
        at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D.<init>(GridCoverage2D.java:186)
        at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverageFactory.create(GridCoverageFactory.java:589)
        at org.geotools.process.raster.RangeLookupProcess.execute(RangeLookupProcess.java:208)
        at org.geotools.process.raster.RangeLookupProcess.execute(RangeLookupProcess.java:234)
        at org.geotools.process.raster.PolygonExtractionProcess.execute(PolygonExtractionProcess.java:167)
        at FooJava.getWktForDbRangeFromRaster(FooJava.java:57)
        at FooJava.main(FooJava.java:36)
```

However, this is not necessarily to be considered as progress, i.e. now even IntelliJ fails to start. It fails with: `ExceptionInInitializerError` due to null pointer exception

Comment: can you open up the fat jar with unzip (or similar) and look to see what is in the services folder and what those files contain

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, see https://github.com/geoHeil/jts-vectorize/tree/master/registryFilesGenerated/META-INF/services for the contents

Comment: Does the code you shared on github works on intelij? (It does not work on my machine)

Comment: It fails with some IO exception, but the orginal issue I reported here in SF is not visible, i.e. that JAI operations registry is not registered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the configuration of descriptors are read from `registryFile.jai` file.(*)

When jar with dependencies is created, registryFile.jai file is overwritten with the last jar's content. 
Merging registryFile.jai contents with the following configuration added to shade plugin corrects this issue. (this is added to github source you provided)

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
   <resource>META-INF/registryFile.jai</resource>
</transformer>
```

(No need to create registryFile.jai in your projects resources/META-INF folder.)

(*) I tried adding [configuration](https://github.com/jdeolive/jai-tools/blob/master/operator/rangelookup/src/main/resources/META-INF/registryFile.jai) to different named file and it did not find the descriptor.
 Even with trying OperationRegistry.updateFromStream(is); command did not worked.